# Java replacing special characters

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace special characters in a file with a pattern with only special characters, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
String special = "Something @$ great @$ that.";
special = special.replaceAll("@$", "as");
```

However, when I run that I get the original string instead of the replaced string.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to do string interpolation, or the example just looks like that? If so, look at [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use [`String#replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) in your case to replace a given `CharSequence`, as next:

```
special = special.replace("@$", "as");
```

Or use [`Pattern.quote(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) to convert your `String` as a literal pattern `String`, as next:

```
special = special.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("@$"), "as");
```

If you intend to do it very frequently, consider reusing the corresponding `Pattern` instance (the class `Pattern` is thread-safe which means that you can share instances of this class) to avoid compiling your regular expression at each call which has a price in term of performances.

So your code could be:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("@$", Pattern.LITERAL);
...
special = PATTERN.matcher(special).replaceAll("as");
```

Answer (score 5):

Escape characters:-

```
    String special = "Something @$ great @$ that.";
    special = special.replaceAll("@\\$", "as");
    System.out.println(special);
```

For Regular Expression, below 12 characters are reserved called as metacharacters. If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex, you need to escape them with a backslash.

```
the backslash \
the caret ^
the dollar sign $
the period or dot .
the vertical bar or pipe symbol |
the question mark ?
the asterisk or star *
the plus sign +
the opening parenthesis (
the closing parenthesis )
the opening square bracket [
and the opening curly brace {
```

references:- http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Answer (score 2):

The method replaceAll accepts regex as a pattern to substitue:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Try simply:

```
special = special.replace("@$", "as");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
special = special.replaceAll("\\W","as");
```

works with all special characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
String special = "Something @$ great @$ that.";

System.out.println(special.replaceAll("[@][$]", "as"));
```

it should be like this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the first given parameter is not a string you want replace. It is a regular expression. You can try to build a regular expression that matches the string you want to replace [on this site](http://regexr.com/).

`special = special.replaceAll("\\@\\$", "as");` would work, as suggested by @Mritunjay