# How can we replace the digits and special characters using the character in String?

Tags: java

There is java program in which I find the digit and special characters in String, same i want to replace the digit and special characters with character 'X'.

This for windows 7

```
String aplhaonly =s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ");
String aplhaDigit =s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java replacing special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673531/java-replacing-special-characters)

Comment: Does your solution not give the desired result (assuming you put `X` as the second argument)?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a need to replace digits and symbols by "X" you probably want to use this:

```
s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "X");
s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "X");
```

The second argument you put in `replaceAll()` is the replacement.

If you need to replace digits and symbols if String contains "X" you can use:

```
if (s.contains("X")) { 
    s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", ""); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for both digit and characters :

```
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("[*^%$#@!&0-9]","X"));
```

for characters only:

```
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("[*^%$#@!&]","X"));
```

for digits only:

```
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("[0-9]","X"));
```